# How to restore a Duplicity backup from Amazon S3 on Debian?

Tags: debian, backup

I have applied the script provided [here](http://linux.justinhartman.com/Automated_Backup_to_Amazon_S3_with_Duplicity_on_Debian_Etch) to backup my stuff in Debian Etch and it works, I tried to reverse the `SOURCE` and `DEST`, but I can't restore. What am I missing?